# How to execute staements as if it was executed within a powershell REPL

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

Basically I want to pass commands `<command>`, as if they were executed within a powershell sessions `PS >`, to be invoked by `CreateProcess`

```
powershell -Command <command>
```

The above doesn't work in all cases. For example, this doesn't work

```
powershell -Command gci "C:\Program Files"
```

Bu this works

```
powershell -Command choco -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Check effective command passed to `powershell` using `{}` scriptblock syntax as follows:

```
powershell -Command {gci "C:\Program Files"}
```

> ```
> gci C:\Program Files
> ```

It appears that `cmd` interpreter *eats off*  double quotes. Hence, you need to *escape* the space inside the `C:\Program Files` string, e.g. as follows:

```
powershell -Command gci "C:\Program` Files" # using backtick
```

or using quotes (any of the following command lines should work):

```
powershell -Command gci """C:\Program Files""" # inner double quotes
powershell -Command gci "'C:\Program Files'"   # inner single quotes
powershell -Command gci 'C:\Program Files'     # single quotes
```

Comment: Are these escaping rules discussed anywhere? 

BTW what do you mean by "Check effective command passed to powershell using {} scriptblock syntax as follows: " ?

I see so apparently this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981177/run-powershell-custom-function-in-new-window/44986341#44986341  provides the correct answer to this question